# MS Word VSTO-Add In SaveAsUI = false not working for MS Word of Office 365 but working for other Versions of MS Word

Tags: c#, office365, vsto, add-in, word-addins

I'm writing a VSTO Add-In for MS Office. My Add-In has to support various versions of MS Office, Starting from Office 2010 to Office 365.

This Add-In enables saving the data directly on cloud. For this I'm suppressing Word's Standard SaveAsUI and showing my Custom Save Dialog.

for suppressing MS Word's Save Dialog:

```
 void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {

        Cancel = true;
        SaveAsUI = false;

 SaveDocument saveDialog = new SaveDocument(Doc, this.Application)
            {
                ChangeCaption = SetWindowCaption
            };
            saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

This works (Not Showing MS Word Save Dialog) in all the versions of office other than Office 365.

How do I suppress the standard Save Dialog in MS Word of Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve this issue. i.e. Suppress the Office 365 Save Dialog.
To Do so:

1. Launch your MS Word
2. Go to File -> Options. It'll launch a Window, **'Word Options'**.
3. Click on '***Save***' tab
4. **Turn On** the Option below and click **'OK'**

   'Don't Show the Backstage when opening or saving files through keyboard shortcuts'

[image: Word Options Dialog]

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thanks for sharing. I had exactly the same issue. Grrr.